# Permission denied errors during Nominatim import

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I'm trying to import the OSM database into postgres using the default importer that Nominatim uses. After a couple of hours, i keep running into a snag. The error message is as follows:

```
index_placex: UPDATE failed: ERROR:  could not open file "base/16386/866592": Permission denied
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE from search_name_138 WHERE place_id = in_place_id"
PL/pgSQL function deletesearchname(integer,bigint) line 50 at SQL statement
PL/pgSQL function placex_update() line 75 at assignment
index_placex: UPDATE failed: ERROR:  could not open file "base/16386/866592": Permission denied
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE from search_name_138 WHERE place_id = in_place_id"
PL/pgSQL function deletesearchname(integer,bigint) line 50 at SQL statement
PL/pgSQL function placex_update() line 75 at assignment
index_placex: UPDATE failed: ERROR:  could not open file "base/16386/866592": Permission denied
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE from search_name_138 WHERE place_id = in_place_id"
PL/pgSQL function deletesearchname(integer,bigint) line 50 at SQL statement
PL/pgSQL function placex_update() line 75 at assignment
index_placex: UPDATE failed: ERROR:  could not open file "base/16386/866592": Permission denied
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE from search_name_138 WHERE place_id = in_place_id"
PL/pgSQL function deletesearchname(integer,bigint) line 50 at SQL statement
PL/pgSQL function placex_update() line 75 at assignment
index_placex: UPDATE failed: ERROR:  could not open file "base/16386/866592": Permission denied
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE from search_name_138 WHERE place_id = in_place_id"
PL/pgSQL function deletesearchname(integer,bigint) line 50 at SQL statement
PL/pgSQL function placex_update() line 75 at assignment
ERROR: Error executing external command: /srv/Nominatim/nominatim/nominatim -i -d nominatim -P 5432 -t 32 -r 26
Error executing external command: /srv/Nominatim/nominatim/nominatim -i -d nominatim -P 5432 -t 32 -r 26
```

Permissions on the data folder:

```
total 44
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres    50 Jan 11 07:56 base
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres   522 Jan 12 10:32 global
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres   184 Jan 12 07:26 pg_clog
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  4232 Jan 11 03:51 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  1636 Jan 11 03:51 pg_ident.conf
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres   216 Jan 16 00:00 pg_log
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres    28 Jan 11 03:51 pg_multixact
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres     8 Jan 11 03:53 pg_notify
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres     0 Jan 11 03:51 pg_serial
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres     0 Jan 11 03:51 pg_snapshots
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres    22 Jan 16 04:19 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres     8 Jan 12 07:48 pg_subtrans
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres     0 Jan 11 03:51 pg_tblspc
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres     0 Jan 11 03:51 pg_twophase
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres     4 Jan 11 03:51 PG_VERSION
drwx------. 1 postgres postgres  9724 Jan 12 13:08 pg_xlog
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 19828 Jan 11 03:53 postgresql.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    57 Jan 11 03:53 postmaster.opts
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    92 Jan 11 03:53 postmaster.pid
```

Any idea on what the issue might be?

This was a fresh install, and it worked earlier on a installation of CentOS 7 server. The only thing that has really changed is that KDE is now installed so I can use X applications.